# How to get the checkbox checked on drop dwon selected index change in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, html-select

HI all i have a an application ..where an Admin assigns the Projetcs to the Employees
so my screen looks like this
i have three Db tables named [Projects],[Employees],[AssignedWork] ..what am i doing is i am binding all the Projects to the DropDwon and all Employees name to the CheckBox dynamically
this is how i am doing it

```
          <div ><a >Project Name : </a><%:Html.DropDownList("Projects")%></div>   

     <div  class="scrool_main" >         
      <% foreach (var item in Model)
         { %>  
             <br />
              <%:Html.CheckBox("EmployeId", new { value = item.EmployeeID, @class = "employeeCheckBox" })%>
              <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.EmployeeName)%>                 
      <%} %> 
       </div>            
        <% if (TempData["notice"] != null) { %>
      <p><label id="msgtext" >Inserted Successfully !!!!</label></p>
      <% } %>        
       </div>
```

this is how i am calling my controller method on drop down change

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Projects").change(function () {
            alert(1);
            var project = document.getElementById("Projects");
            var SelProj = project.options[project.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(SelProj);
            if (SelProj != "") {
                alert("hi");
                var PorjectId;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("GetAssignedWork","Project") %>',
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    data: {ProjectId:SelProj}
                })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my controller Action

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult GetAssignedWork(string ProjectId)
    {
        ViewBag.Projects = new SelectList(GetProjects(), "ProjectId", "ProjectName");
        var EmployeeList = new List<ResourceModel>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("select EmployeID from AssignedWork where ProjectID='" + ProjectId + "'", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(dCmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
               //need help here for getting the checkbox checked
            }                
            return View("AssignWork",EmployeeList);
        }
    }
```

so what i want is if Admin selects the project  from dropdown on selected index change the previously Assigned employees to that project should be checked..i mean the employee who is already assigned to the project should be checked...so how should i do this

Answer (score 0):

> The Visual Studio templates for both an empty and a "starter" version
>   of MVC provide a Scripts directory that contains jQuery. - 
>   [Reference](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_in_mvc.ashx)

Include it -

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

$(function(){
    $('#Projects').change(function(){
      var isChecked = $('#EmployeId').is(':checked');
    });
});
```